# Como acessar um json com jquery que esta sendo passado por php

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, laravel, fullcalendar

Estou passando um json para minha view e preciso jogalo dentro do events do full calendar, mas nao sei como acessar esse json atraves da minha URL

no meu localhost a rota da view que recebe o json é essa

"http://condofacil.com.br/dashboard/reservaArea"

```
$(function() {
    $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
        events: 'http://condofacil.com.br/dashboard/reservaArea',
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

No PHP você faz o fechamento enviando o json_encode() dos dados?

Se sim, você faz a apuração do callback usando uma função:

`events: function(callback){`
#seu código
`}`